# How can I keep the ordering of JSON if I want to get two JSON elements into new dictionary

Tags: python, json

I want to get from a webpage the shopids and the prices based on a URL for each product. From a JSON load an ordered dictionary of only two JSON elements. I pass in load the OrderedDict argument and sort the json load based on element. I do the following but the final ordered dict is not in order. Is there any other way?

```
mystr = [{"id":36887154,"final_price":1986.05,"payment_method_cost":"\\u003cem\\u003e+ 3,00 €\\u003c/em\\u003e \\u003cspan\\u003eΑντικαταβολή\\u003c/span\\u003e","net_price":1983.05,"net_price_formatted":"1.983,05 €","final_price_formatted":"1.986,05 €","shop_id":514,"no_credit_card":false,"sorting_score":[-4.8549,-340,-83,514,40],"shipping_cost":"\\u003cem\\u003e+ 0,00 €\\u003c/em\\u003e \\u003cspan\\u003eΜεταφορικά\\u003c/span\\u003e","link":"/products/show/36887154"},{"id":37336259,"final_price":1825.0,"payment_method_cost":"\\u003cem\\u003e+ 2,00 €\\u003c/em\\u003e \\u003cspan\\u003eΑντικαταβολή\\u003c/span\\u003e","net_price":1819.0,"net_price_formatted":"1.819,00 €","final_price_formatted":"1.825,00 €","shop_id":597,"no_credit_card":false,"sorting_score":[-4.71702,-57,-95,597,40],"shipping_cost":"\\u003cem\\u003e+ 4,00 €\\u003c/em\\u003e \\u003cspan\\u003eΜεταφορικά\\u003c/span\\u003e","link":"/products/show/37336259"}]

 fp = urllib.request.urlopen(url2besearched)
 mybytes = fp.read()
 mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")
 fp.close()
 mystr = mystr.rsplit('=')
 mystr = mystr[1].split(";")
 mystr = mystr[0]


 if mystr.endswith("]"):
        json_str = json.loads(mystr, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
        #sort json list
        json_str.sort(key=lambda s: s['final_price'])
        #get first
        spid = json_str[0]['shop_id']
        fprice = json_str[0]['final_price']
 else:
        mystr = json.dumps(mystr)
        json_str = json.loads(mystr, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
        json_str.sort(key=lambda s: s['final_price'])
        #get first
        spid = json_str[0]['shop_id']
        fprice = json_str[0]['final_price']

i =0
json_dict = OrderedDict()    
for i in range(len(json_str)):
    key = json_str[i]["shop_id"]
    value = json_str[i]["final_price"]
    json_dict.update( {key : value} )
```

I want to get an ordered dictionary of shop_id and final_price based on final price in ascending order but I have two major problems the

json_dict is not in order
I get errors from mystr that this str has no attribute sort

Answer (score 0):

`OrderedDict` is designed to keep the addition order of the entries. Here you don't need that, you need to sort the dictionary based on the final price:

```
payments = json.loads(mystr)
final_prices = sorted([
    (payment['shop_id'], payment['final_price'])
    for payment in payments
], key=lambda payment: payment[1])
```

If, for some reason, you still need an `OrderedDict` from this, you can do so with:

```
OrderedDict(final_prices)
```